# JSON data should not have key value in numeric and result not coming as per expected result

Tags: php, json

I am creating JSON with nested set model using recursion. My result is not coming as expected, as this JSON helps me to generate a tree. The brackets are not coming as in required JSON.

i am trying to create a json like this http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/evolution-tree/example6.js . i am interested in     **nodeStructure: { }**

Issue:

1. every children has { } but required [ ]
2. Not required numeric keys
3. json keys should not come in quotes like "text", "children, "name" , its should come witout quotes

Online compiler: https://3v4l.org/UsXPv

```
<?php
  $category = '{"9":{"id":"9","btc_mlm_user_id":"0","lft":"1","rht":"16","lvl":"0","name":"Root","created":"2017-06-27 05:56:11","modified":"2017-06-27 05:56:11","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":""},"42":{"id":"42","btc_mlm_user_id":"25","lft":"2","rht":"13","lvl":"1","name":"naresh","created":"2017-11-02 10:22:24","modified":"2017-11-02 10:22:24","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"naresh"},"44":{"id":"44","btc_mlm_user_id":"27","lft":"3","rht":"4","lvl":"2","name":"rahul1","created":"2017-11-02 10:25:53","modified":"2017-11-02 10:25:53","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"rahul1"},"45":{"id":"45","btc_mlm_user_id":"28","lft":"5","rht":"6","lvl":"2","name":"rahul123","created":"2017-11-02 10:27:19","modified":"2017-11-02 10:27:19","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"rahul123"},"46":{"id":"46","btc_mlm_user_id":"29","lft":"7","rht":"12","lvl":"2","name":"kapil1","created":"2017-11-02 10:28:20","modified":"2017-11-02 10:28:20","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"kapil1"},"47":{"id":"47","btc_mlm_user_id":"30","lft":"8","rht":"11","lvl":"3","name":"priya12","created":"2017-11-02 10:30:30","modified":"2017-11-02 10:30:30","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"priya12"},"48":{"id":"48","btc_mlm_user_id":"31","lft":"9","rht":"10","lvl":"4","name":"amit12","created":"2017-11-02 10:32:00","modified":"2017-11-02 10:32:00","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"amit12"},"43":{"id":"43","btc_mlm_user_id":"26","lft":"14","rht":"15","lvl":"1","name":"roshan","created":"2017-11-02 10:24:27","modified":"2017-11-02 10:24:27","first_name":"","last_name":"","username":"roshan"}}';

  function tree($data, $left = 0, $right = null) 
  {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
    {
      if ($value['lft'] == $left + 1 && (is_null($right) || $value['rht'] < $right)) 
      {
        $tree[$key]['text']  = ['name' => $value['name']];
        $tree[$key]['children'] = tree($data, $value['lft'], $value['rht']);
        $left = $value['rht'];
      }
    }
    return $tree;
  }

  $tree = tree(json_decode($category, true));
  echo json_encode($tree);
```

Output:

```js
{
  "9": {
    "text": {
      "name": "Root"
    },
    "children": {
      "42": {
        "text": {
          "name": "naresh"
        },
        "children": {
          "44": {
            "text": {
              "name": "rahul1"
            },
            "children": []
          },
          "45": {
            "text": {
              "name": "rahul123"
            },
            "children": []
          },
          "46": {
            "text": {
              "name": "kapil1"
            },
            "children": {
              "47": {
                "text": {
                  "name": "priya12"
                },
                "children": {
                  "48": {
                    "text": {
                      "name": "amit12"
                    },
                    "children": []
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "43": {
        "text": {
          "name": "roshan"
        },
        "children": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Required output:

```js
{
  text: {
    name: "Root"
  },
  children: [{
    text: {
      name: "naresh"
    },
    children: [{
      text: {
        name: "rahul1"
      },
      children: [
        []
      ],
      text: {
        name: "rahul123"
      },
      children: [
        []
      ],
      text: {
        name: "kapil1"
      },
      children: [{
        text: {
          name: "priya12"
        },
        children: [{
          text: {
            name: "amit12"
          },
          children: [
            []
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }],
    text: {
      name: "roshan"
    },
    children: [
      []
    ]
  }]
}
```

Here is my MySql records which are i am fetching here to show you in **$category** json in start.

[image]

Comment: your actual and required outputs appear to be the same. Did you paste the wrong thing?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry - that was my mistake in the edit. Not the OPs fault.

Comment: @Johan the data structure you're trying to create is not valid as you have repeated the same key name within objects

Comment: my json required here http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/evolution-tree/example6.js

Comment: You have your numbers in the output because you are using the $key : `$tree[$key]['text']` & `$tree[$key]['children']`.
If you use `$tree['text']` & `$tree['children']`instead you'll still have an issue with "roshan" because the keys "text" and "children" will already exist in your array but it will be closer to your required output.

Comment: i updated my question . please take a look one time more

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its nested set model. and i am trying to build a json which can support to the tree graph plugin..

Comment: your "required" output is still invalid, so we can't help you achieve that. You can't have multiple properties called "text" in the same object, for instance. children needs to be an array of multiple objects, not an array containing a single object (which then contains multiple repeated properties) which you have now.

Comment: ADyson :  my required json structure like http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/evolution-tree/example6.js here in this example and i am only looking at nodeStructure: { } .. this one give me a tree graph with json. so i am trying to build it... hope you can suggest me more..

Comment: ok well that's not the same as the desired structure you've posted in the question, is it? Please update the question with what you actually want, in that case. If you can't see the difference, look more carefully at the example you linked to.

Comment: that seems same as please look at     nodeStructure: {  } in reference.. some keys in     nodeStructure: { }  are optional and that i dont have in my example.

Comment: http://myjson.com/df9ib would be a valid version of your suggested output. Your version fails validation at https://jsonlint.com/, for example (even after you put double quotes round all the property names, as it required). As has already been pointed out to you multiple times, you can't have several properties with the same name within the same object. You seem to be just ignoring that fact. Nothing to do with optional keys etc. It's just simply invalid, un-parseable data. You didn't accurately copy the basic structure as per your example link, regardless of the optional fields.

Comment: Adyson: I repeated lot of time that I am looking at this http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/evolution-tree/example6.js

Comment: I know. And I'm saying that your reproduction of it is inaccurate and invalid. What part of that is difficult to understand? You should put in the question something which actually makes sense. External links are no good, especially when you don't actually want that whole structure, you seem to want a subset of it. But if you don't show a valid structure, then it's hard to be 100% sure what you actually need. I linked above to what I _suspect_ is the structure you really want. It would be sensible if you confirm that or not, and if that's correct, then update your question to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the [output you linked](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/evolution-tree/example6.js), rather than the one in your question (which is invalid [as pointed by @RoryMcCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078362/json-data-should-not-have-key-value-in-numeric-and-result-not-coming-as-per-expe#comment81106088_47078362), because it contains multiple equal keys per object), then you can change your code to this:

```
function tree($data, $left = 0, $right = null) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['lft'] == $left + 1 && (is_null($right) || $value['rht'] < $right)) {
            $child = []; // Let's make a new child
            $child['text'] = ['name' => $value['name']]; // The text is required
            $childTree = tree($data, $value['lft'], $value['rht']); // Let's find its children
            if (!empty($childTree)) { // If it has children
                $child['children'] = $childTree; // Let's save the children
            }
            $tree[] = $child; // Put the child in the tree
            $left = $value['rht'];
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

$tree = tree(json_decode($category, true))[0]; // Since there's only one root, you want the first element of the tree
```

Here's the full code: https://3v4l.org/AYCGt

That just leaves you with one problem, according to you, the keys shouldn't have quotes around them. Although I don't really know your motives and it should work with the quotes in Javascript, you could do some replacements using `preg_replace`, like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/"(\w+)":/','$1:',json_encode($tree));
```

This would be the complete code: https://3v4l.org/ZaXip

Comment: "the keys shouldn't have quotes around them". Really? Why? The strictest JSON standards actually require that they do. Browsers are often a little more lenient, but they don't have to be. Trying parsing something through https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ without quotes round the keys...

Comment: Well, that's what @Johan said. I'm against it, but maybe the use of the code would be to generate as clean Javascript as possible. Perhaps that's why the question used to have Javasript tags. Maybe a JSON would be wasting characters

Comment: based on the other comments above unfortunately it appears the OP doesn't understand (and seemingly doesn't want to understand) what constitutes valid JSON, so perhaps that's got something do with it, but I couldn't say for sure. Javascript doesn't really care whether quotes are used or not, so it's hard to see why it matters - no-one will really see the data like this, normally. It'd be better to produce something which adheres to the standard, and json_encode() does this automatically. Just my opinion but it seems a waste of time and CPU to then go through removing the quotes.

Comment: I agree with you, seems like a waste of resources, but then again we don't really know what @Johan wants with the final code. If a JSON is not really necessary, then having the quotes is irrelevant as they would become a waste of space. So maybe the trade of processing for space is useful in Johan's case